# Characterizing subgroups of R^n with dense factors

Tags: algebraic-groups, discrete-geometry

It is well known that (additive) subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are products of discrete subgroups (lattices) by dense subgroups in subspaces. My question is the following: given a generator set of $p$ vectors (obviously $p>n$), can one tell (i) whether there will be dense factors, if so (ii) what their dimensions will be (i.e. the dimension of the subspace it is dense in) and (iii) give a basis of these subsets in terms of the generator set. 
This answer is probably more algorithmic than explicit, but I am looking at specific examples in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where the generators are two orthonormal frames), so hopefully one might say something conclusive there.

To clarify what I mean by an algorithm (thanks @Ycor), let me quote the (trivial) example of $n=1$, $p=2$. My "algorithm" would go as follows: are the two generators commensurable? If not, the subgroup is dense. Similarly, if all vectors in the generator set have rationals coordinates, then I know that the subgroup is a lattice. I do not wish for a computer automated procedure (otherwise, one would go into the problems of representing numbers, etc. which is not my goal). I want either a direct criterion, or a deciding procedure, in other words an algorithm.

Any reference will be welcome.

Comment: Even for $n=1$ and $p=2$, you cannot answer in a simple way because otherwise you would be able to determine whether a given number is irrational. Of course it depends on what you mean by "given a set" and "one can tell". If you ask at an algorithmic level, you have to wonder how you make the input.

Comment: Point taken. I wasn’t clear enough on what I meant by algorithm. I have corrected it in the question.

Comment: So let's say we set $n=1$ and $p=2$, and I give you $a=\pi$ and $b=e$. What does your "algorithm" give then?

Comment: Algorithm is for me the same as computer automated procedure, except maybe that we describe its mathematical contents rather than the implementation. But the coding problem is essential then. Or you want a criterion, not an algorithm.

Comment: It's unknown whether $\pi/e$ is irrational? (I remember that it's unknown whether $(1,e,\pi)$ is $\mathbf{Q}$-linearly free but this is a bit stronger.)

Comment: If $G$ is a subgroup of ${\bf R}^n$, and is free on $n+1$ generators, then $G$ is dense iff the set of determinants of the $n$-element subsets is rationally linearly independent. [By the set of determinants, I mean the set of numbers obtained by deleting one of the generators, and making the rest of them into an $n\times n$ matrix and taking its determinant, one for each generator deleted.] This can be used to obtain criteria for density of finitely generated subgroups. For non-finitely generated subgroups, the situation is more complicated; but there probably is some criterion.

Comment: Alternatively, a subgroup $G$ is dense if for every nonzero linear functional $\gamma$, on ${\bf R}^n$, the image, $\gamma(G) $, is dense in ${\bf R}$. This looks ungainly, but can be used to prove density results of the type mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @eric Then I'm stuck. Admittedly, I might run into such problems, but what I am looking for is more in the spirit of the criterion in David Handelman's comment, reducing the problem to simpler ones.

Comment: @david-handelman : This is the type of results I'm looking for, with more generators (finitely many). Any suggestion of books/articles I should look into?

Comment: I think David has the right idea. My earlier point was just that the word "algorithm" was not being used according to its standard definition. Let's go with "criterion". Here's a question which is probably attackable and which the OP might like. Say $G$ is a finitely-generated subgroup of $R^n$. Then the closure of $G$ is, I guess, isomorphic to $Z^a\times R^b$ for some $a$ and $b$. Can we read off $a$ and $b$ in terms of dimension of some $Q$-span of some minors built from the coordinates of generators of $G$, or some such thing? This sounds feasible.